# What network settings need to be changed in order to access my guest oracle linux pre-built VM from my host?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, oracle-linux, oracle-database

I just downloaded and successfully installed [this oracle linux/database pre-built virtual machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa-172279.html).

I was successfully able to login as oracle/oracle user and view the desktop with the red-colored wall paper.

I opened the terminal and did "ifconfig -a" and noticed my IP address is 10.0.2.15, however if I try to access it from my host machine (something like http://10.0.2.15:8080 for a tomcat server) I am unsuccessful.

I tried to modify the network settings in Virtual Box from NAT to Bridged, hoping that it would give me some kind of a DHCP IP address (like one of those 192.168.x.x).  However, after rebooting into the pre-built virtual machine and rerunning "ifconfig" the 10.0.2.15 IP address disappeared but was not replaced with a DCHP IP address.

How do I get my host operating system (Yosemite) to connect to a server running on my pre-built oracle virtual machine? What do I need to change in Virtual Box's settings?

I have Virtual Box 5.x so it is one of the more recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation linked on the page you linked, port 8080 has no service running.

Please read the [pdf](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/virtualboxps6readme2-2168473.pdf) starting at point 5.2

Also changed back the configuration to NAT. For instance, with your browser try `http://10.0.2.15:8888/webcenter/spaces` for Oracle's Webcenter Spaces.

All necessary information is provided in the document.

Comment: I changed back the configuration to NAT and attempted to access the link http://10.0.2.15:8888/webcenter/spaces and it did not work.  In fact, I attempted to navigate into several links bookmarked in firefox, none of which worked. Does this mean I need to start these servers ?

Comment: bookmarked in firefox suggests you mean the firefox that's running inside the virtual machine? but yes, the documentation mentions steps to configure everything and how to start and stop everything, I suggest taking some time and just reading the pdf whole